# How to Adjust Vertical Spacing in an egreg Macro Between the Endnotes within Each Chapter

Tags: macros, pdftex, chapters, vertical-spacing, endnotes

The following code has been modified from an answer posted by egreg in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}

\usepackage{endnotes,chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{endnote}{chapter}  % Reset endnote numbering every new chapter


\let\latexchapter\chapter
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\enoteheading{%
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
  \latexchapter*{\notesname\markboth{NOTES}{}}
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip
  \let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{xparse}


\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{som}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}
  {\latexchapter*{#3}%
   \setcounter{endnote}{0}%
   \addtoendnotes{%
     \noexpand\enotedivision{\noexpand\subsection}
       {\unexpanded{#3}}}%
  }
  {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
     {\latexchapter{#3}}
     {\latexchapter[#2]{#3}}%
   \addtoendnotes{%
     \noexpand\enotedivision{\noexpand\subsection}
       {\chaptername\ \thechapter. \unexpanded{#3}}}%
  }%
}
\makeatletter
\def\enotedivision#1#2{\@ifnextchar\enotedivision{}{#1{#2}}}
\makeatletter


\begin{document}
\chapter*{Chapter I}
This is Chapter I.\endnote{First endnote.} This is a sentence in Chapter I.\endnote{Second note.}

\chapter*{Chapter II}
In this Chapter II.\endnote{The only endnote in Chapter II.}

\chapter*{Chapter III}
This is Chapter III.\endnote{This is part of a long endnote. This is part of a long endnote. This is part of a long endnote. This is part of a long endnote. This is part of a long endnote. This is part of a long endnote.} This is a sentence in Chapter III.\endnote{This is part of another long endnote. This is part of another long endnote. This is part of another long endnote. This is part of another long endnote. This is part of another long endnote.}

%\cleardoublepage
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

And gives the Endnotes list:

[image]

If I wanted to adjust the spacing between the actual endnotes within each chapter (which in this case appears to be none), how could I specify such a vertical spacing?

Also, as an aside, the command `\cleardoublepage` is commented out in the code. If I include it, for some strange reason to me, I get an extra page inserted before the Endnotes list. Why might this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set  `\setlength{\skipnote}{<length>}` to add more space between notes.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}

\usepackage{endnotes,chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{endnote}{chapter}  % Reset endnote numbering every new chapter


\newlength{\skipnote}
\setlength{\skipnote}{2ex} % set inter notes vertical space <<<<<<<<<<<

\let\latexchapter\chapter
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\enoteheading{%
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
    \latexchapter*{\notesname\markboth{NOTES}{}}
    \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip
    \let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue
}
% **************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,
\def\@endanenote{\par\vskip\skipnote\endgroup}%
% ****************  

\makeatother

\usepackage{xparse}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{som}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\latexchapter*{#3}%
        \setcounter{endnote}{0}%
        \addtoendnotes{%
            \noexpand\enotedivision{\noexpand\subsection}
            {\unexpanded{#3}}}%
    }
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\latexchapter{#3}}
        {\latexchapter[#2]{#3}}%
        \addtoendnotes{%
            \noexpand\enotedivision{\noexpand\subsection}
            {\chaptername\ \thechapter. \unexpanded{#3}}}%
    }%
}
\makeatletter
\def\enotedivision#1#2{\@ifnextchar\enotedivision{}{#1{#2}\vskip0pt}}
\makeatletter


\begin{document}
    \chapter*{Chapter I}
    This is Chapter I.\endnote{First endnote.} This is a sentence in Chapter I.\endnote{Second note.}
    
    \chapter*{Chapter II}
    In this Chapter II.\endnote{The only endnote in Chapter II.}
    
    \chapter*{Chapter III}
    This is Chapter III.\endnote{This is part of a long endnote. This is part of a long endnote. This is part of a long endnote. This is part of a long endnote. This is part of a long endnote. This is part of a long endnote.} This is a sentence in Chapter III.\endnote{This is part of another long endnote. This is part of another long endnote. This is part of another long endnote. This is part of another long endnote. This is part of another long endnote.}
    
    %\cleardoublepage
    \theendnotes
\end{document}
```

`\cleardoublepage` or `\clearpage` are unnecessary.

`\theendnote` behaves like a chapter and thus starts a new page.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work quite nicely.